# How to fix "unable to load CLR" in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

My error:

> Unable to load the CLR. If a CLR version was specified for debugging, check that it was valid and installed on the machine. If the problem persists, please repair your Microsoft .NET Framework installation via 'Programs and Features' in Control Panel.

I'm getting this error when trying to debug my solution. I have tried everything I know to fix it:

- I repaired the .NET framework.
- I uninstalled and re-installed all .NET frameworks and Visual Studio.
- I changed several options and I made sure my solution was using the right .NET framework.
- I made sure my paths are correct.
- I'm targeting .NET 4.6.2 (if I try a lower version, I get compilation errors).
- Deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders and trying again doesn't help.

I'm not getting this for other solutions - just this one.

Comment: There is not a lot of information on this problem online, seems to be uncommon.

Comment: Does the solution have more than one project? If so, are they *all* set to use 4.6.2? Can you remember if anything changed (e.g. a Windows update) to make it stop working?

Comment: It does. Yes, I made sure all projects have 4.6.2 framework set. I have never been able to successfully debug it. Building works fine, but the debugger gives me the CLR error.

Comment: @Nack A) If you look at the .sln file in a text editor and compare it to a known-good one, does anything stand out as looking wrong? B) Can you make a new solution to re-create it by adding one project at a time, seeing if debug works after adding each one?

Comment: I tried that as well, but does not change. I'm uninstalling windows and reinstalling.

Comment: Please let us know if that worked.

Comment: I uninstalled windows. I still get the error. I'm at a loss of words.

Comment: How about targeting .NET 4.7.2 instead? If that is viable.

Answer (score -1):

**Re-Installation** of Visual Studio may fix this issue.